# Gnuplot : Size of points

Tags: file, graph, size, gnuplot, point

I want to do a graph with different sizes of points on it. Is it possible to do it with only one file and to specify the size of each points in the file?

Example of file:

```
1 2 Size1
2 3 Size2
```

I want to draw the point `(1,2)` with size `Size1` and the point `(2,3)` with size `Size2`.

I know I can do this making different files (i.e. one file for each size of points) but it would really help me if I can do this with only one file.

Comment: Why was this question closed?  I see absolutely no reason why this is "off topic".  OP has a **specific question** which is reasonably answerable.  Granted, it could use a *little* help with clarity and formatting, but I would say this is a pretty good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pointsize variable` in the plot command:

```
plot "data.txt" using 1:2:3 with points pointsize variable
```

For an example, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pointsize.html